# Materialize - Using Carousel functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I just want to use the carousel from [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html) with the following features : I want to use it on full width, with navigations buttons and the specials fixed-item option.

But the navigations buttons doesn't work.
Here is the code I used to test that!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
    $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({fullWidth: true});
    $('.slide-prev').carousel('prev');
    $('.slide-next').carousel('next');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
        <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2 slide-prev">Prev</a>
        <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">Share</a>
        <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2 slide-next">Next</a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
        <h2>First Panel</h2>
        <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
        <h2>Second Panel</h2>
        <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
        <h2>Third Panel</h2>
        <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
        <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
        <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong here?
Thank you for your help!
~W~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need have click handlers for the buttons which stop the propagation and perform the needed operation on the carousel element, instead of performing it on the button element.

Here is a snippet:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({ fullWidth: true });
    $('.slide-prev').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.carousel').carousel('prev')
    });
    $('.slide-next').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.carousel').carousel('next')
    });
});
```

Here is a Codepen to see it work: https://codepen.io/zubair1024/pen/mBaEdX

For navigation (programmatically) use the following:

```
 //this is for navigation using a new tab
        $('.share-btn').click(function (e) {
            var win = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
            win.focus();
        });
```

Comment: Just a little question about the "Share", if I would like to go on an external website following a href link, it doesn't work .. Any idea about this problem?

Comment: @Blup, I have edited the codepen as well with the change: https://codepen.io/zubair1024/pen/mBaEdX Cheers Mate!